# Doubly Linked list in python Using Del

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I was analyzing a doubly linked list function that deletes a node. However Im a bit confused.

```
def remove( self, p ) :
        tmp = p.prev
        p.prev.next = p.next
        p.prev = tmp
```

Why is there a tmp = p.prev and p.prev = tmp. What is the purpose of those extra line? and finally, why is no nodes being deleted with "del"? shouldn't it be "del p" at the end of the code?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you the same user who asked about a linked list insert a couple weeks ago? If so, did you find the ASCII diagrams in the answer helpful?

Comment: oh no that wasn't me lol

Comment: It would be utterly pointless to do `del p` in this function - the caller obviously holds a reference to this list node, so it cannot be garbage collected yet.  `del p` would only get rid of the local reference to the node, but that's going away anyway when the function ends.  (The function is broken, anyway: you'd also need to set `p.next.prev` to remove the node from the backwards chain.)

Comment: Well, if you want some bad ASCII art diagrams that might just confuse you more, let me know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if this is the entire function, it's wrong, which is probably part of the reason you're having trouble understand it.

To remove a node from a doubly linked list, you need to do three things:

1. Make the previous node point ahead at the next node, instead of the `p` node.
2. Make the next node point back at the previous node, instead of the current one.
3. Delete the current node.

Because Python is garbage-collected,<sup>1</sup> step 3 happens automatically.<sup>2</sup>

And step 1 is taken care of by `p.prev.next = p.next`.

But step 2 doesn't happen anywhere. `p.next.prev` is still pointing at `p`, instead of at `p.prev`. This means that if you walk the list forward, `p` won't be part of it—but if you walk backward, it *will*. So `p` isn't actually removed.

Meanwhile, `tmp = p.prev` followed by `p.prev = tmp` doesn't do anything useful.<sup>3</sup> And, whatever it was *trying* to do, you almost never need `tmp` like that in Python; you can swap values with just `x, y = y, x` instead of `tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp`.

---

So, what you actually *want* here is:

```
def remove(self, p):
    p.prev.next = p.next
    p.next.prev = p.prev
```

---

<sub>1. CPython, the reference interpreter for Python that you're probably using, does garbage collection through automated reference counting, with a cycle breaker that runs occasionally. Whether this counts as "real" garbage collection or not is a nice holy-war argument, but it doesn't matter here.</sub>

<sub>2. You just need to drop all references to the object, and it becomes garbage and gets cleaned up automatically. So, you need to remove the references from the next and previous nodes to `p`, which you're already doing. And you need to let `p` go away, but you don't need `del p` for that—it's a local variable; it goes away when you return from the function. After that, it's up to the caller of `remove`; if they don't keep any references to the node, the node is garbage.</sub>

<sub>3. It *could* do something useful, if we temporarily assigned a different value to `p.prev` and wanted to restore it at the end of the function. But that isn't happening here, and I don't think whoever wrote this code intended anything like that; I think they were trying to do some kind of swap.</sub>